# GCP App Engine: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have deployed a flask app on GCP app engine that I'm using for uploading files to GCP bucket storage and then download the file from the storage when required. However, I'm encountering the error **OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:** when I try to download the file from cloud storage. I can properly upload the file from the app which I've deployed on app engine and I verified the file was uploaded, but when I try to download from the website I get error. Any idea would be appreciated?

Code for Downloading the File from Bucket

```
 storage_client = storage.Client()

 bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
 blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
 blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
```

PS: I'm using google-cloud-storage==1.33.0

Comment: Sounds like the destination where you're trying to write the downloaded file is read-only.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for the comment! Could you please provide guidance on how I can download it to specific folder? I tried specifiying the folder path using os.path but got another error :(

Comment: The usual way is to use `f = open("/some/path/to/filename", "w")` and then `f.write(content)`.

Comment: Nope that doesn't help either.. still same error

Comment: Are you trying to download the files to your app or to an and user?  If to your app, then the answer below works though also consider using BytesIO for an in-memory file if the files are not large.  If to an end user, then you can provide the user with a link to download it directly from cloud storage and bypass your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no writable hard drive in App Engine, if you need to write a temporary file use `/tmp` folder as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files). Don't forget to delete it to release system's RAM or it will crash at some point.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For now at least my app is working as expected and I can get going with my work! But just curious if I upload files to cloud storage via my app engine which I was able to successfully isn't there any way to download those files back through app hosted on the app engine?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, are you trying to open the file without saving it first? Then you can try [download_as_bytes](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_as_bytes) method maybe.